# Bootstrap on Safari in Tablet: navigation menu gets under heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

Good day!

I developed a website with bootstrap and works fine in the main browsers/devices. Only on a apple tablet with Safari I noticed an annoying displaying problem of the navigation menu against the page heading [image: The visualization on tablet]

I searched but couldn't find any answer which works for this specific case. Anybody can help?
The code can be found [here](http://www.twv.at/sport-ergebnisse-tirol_meisterschaft_schwimmen_2014.htm?jahr=2014).
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is the structuring problem. You have to modify your html structure like this.

So, your html will be like following:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="main-content">
<h1>INNSBRUCK: Tivoli: Tiroler Meisterschaften 27.6.-29.6.2014</h1>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bericht">Bericht</a></li>
...........
</div>
</div>
```

And Give z-index like following:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu { z-index:11; }
.main-content { position:relative; z-index:1; }
```